# Wrapping quotation marks in <span>, in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, regex, wordpress

Is there a way to wrap specific characters (in a `<span>` element), like the quotation marks at the beginning and end of a text, in Wordpress?

**TL;DR:** search and replace `"` with `<span>"</span>` in the body text. Something like this?

`update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'Text to find','text to replace with');`

To make the example easier to imagine, imagine having a quote that has different color punctuation than the text. I don't want to do that from the editor, I want a hook or something that wraps the quotation marks it finds in `<span>` so I can style it from css.

So far I'm using the [WP Typography](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-typography/) plugin to achieve this but it wraps only the **first** quotation mark & not the **last**...

I have looked at the code trying to reverse-engineer it but unfortunately I am not at that level (yet). It seems daunting that I couldn't find anything on Google, either, no matter how I tried to search.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

**Later edit #01:** I *think* the plugin is using a text parser with regex to find the quotation marks. The question is, isn't this going to severely impact the performance of the website? And if so, what is a smart way to do this? Should I just use js and manipulate the DOM instead?

**Later edit #02:**
I *think* is one of the regex the plugin uses to find the quotation html entity in the body text:

`(?: &(?:quot|amp|frasl|lt|gt|iexcl|cent|pound|curren|yen|brvbar|sect|uml|pound|ordf|laquo|not|reg|macr|deg|plusmn|sup2|sup3|acute|micro|para|middot|cedil|sup1|ordm|raquo|frac14|frac12|frac34|iquest|times|divide|circ|tilde|thetasym|upsih|piv|ndash|mdash|lsquo|rsquo|sbquo|ldquo|rdquo|bdquo|dagger|Dagger|bull|hellip|permil|prime|Prime|lsaquo|rsaquo|oline|frasl|euro|trade|alefsym|larr|uarr|rarr|darr|harr|crarr|lArr|uArr|rArr|dArr|hArr|forall|part|exist|emptyn|abla|isin|notin|ni|prod|sum|minus|lowast|radic|prop|infin|ang|and|orc|ap|cup|int|there4|simc|ong|asymp|ne|equiv|le|ge|sub|supn|sub|sube|supe|oplus|otimes|perp|sdot|lceil|rceil|lfloor|rfloor|lang|rang|loz|spades|clubs|hearts|diams);
)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, you want to add quotation on already rendered quote. You can do this using **:after** and **:before** selectors.

For example:

```css
span:before {
  content: "''";
}

span:after {
  content: "''";
}
```

```html
    <span>I have no quotation marks!</span>
```

Comment: This is definitely a simpler and possibly more performance-oriented solution, however there will be multiple people adding content so I have to assume low consistency when it comes to text input. Which is why I am looking at a way to add classes to already written content. i.e. search and replace `"` with `<span class="">"</span>`. Thanks!

Comment: Again, if I understood this alright, you want to find spans that contain quotes and then assign them classes? If so, you would need jQuery for this.

Comment: No, I want to find quotation marks and add spans :)

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, that I didn't totally understood the problem. So here is the answer to what arrived me:

If you want to add sprecific CSS to child objects, you can use the css child selector:

```
<div class="container">
<span>This</span>
<span>is my</span>
<span>Text</span>
<span>?!</span>
</div>
```

So in your css you can set the properties this way:

```
.container > span:first-child {
    color: red;
}
.container > span:last-child {
    color: green;
}
.container > span:nth-child(2) {
    color: yellow;
}
.container > span:nth-child(3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am looking for a way to search and replace `"` with `<span>"</span>` — in the body text, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that seems to do what I want, however I just need to find the right html entity for the quotation marks. Works with letters but not punctuation:

```
`function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('replace this', 'with this', $text);
    $text = str_replace('replace this', 'with this', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');`
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?

Comment: 99% there. I can't seem to be able to select `"`, it works for regular letters like a,b,c though. Quotation marks don't work even if I use escaped html entities :(

Comment: But are you posting this as an answer to your question?

Comment: A partial answer, yes.

Comment: It says I can't accept my own answer in 2 days. But it works. 99%.

Comment: The reason I ask is some people will post add on information for their question here instead of editing their question. If this is the answer to your question then you're good but make note of that.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Roger that.